# struct for parsing google distance json in swif

Tags: json, swift, google-distancematrix-api

This is the json output from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=rijssen&destinations=almelo&mode=driving&language=en&key=

```
   { "destination_addresses" : [ "Almelo, Netherlands" ],
     "origin_addresses" : [ "Rijssen, Netherlands" ],
     "rows" : [
       {
         "elements" : [
          {
             "distance" : {
              "text" : "14.1 km",
              "value" : 14090
           },
             "duration" : {
              "text" : "21 mins",
              "value" : 1267
           },
             "status" : "OK"
        }
       ]
     }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
    }
```

this is the struct in Swift

```
struct Model: Codable{
let destination_addresses : [String]
let origin_addresses : [String]
let rows : [Elements]
let status : String
  }
struct Elements: Codable {
let elements:[Distance]
  }
struct Distance: Codable{
let distance:Value
let duration:Value
let status:String
  }
struct Value: Codable{
let text:String
let value:Int
 }
```

This is the api request

```
guard let url = URL(string: api) else { return }
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    do {
     if let data = data {
       let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
```

error in compiler

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Why is the code not working?
Thank you i.a.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io

Comment: you are trying to decode an array of [Model], where the data is only for 1 Model. Hint, use Model, not [Model].